# Missing link to keybindings.json in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

The [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization) refers to a link to `keybindings.json`. This link is not present in my editor (see image). How can it be restored?

[image: image of VS Code keyboard shortcuts]

Where is `keybindings.json` located in Windows 10?

VS Code version: 1.29.0-insider (user setup)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tested this both on 1.28.0 and 1.29.0-insider. It seems that the link in question doesn't exist on the insider version. On my 1.28.0 installation, I can click the link and it will go to keybindings.json, which is found in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json`. This link exists even if the file itself is deleted, and will create a new file at that location if you click it.

In the insider's version however, the link is gone, and the insider keybindings.json is installed for me by default in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code - Insiders\User\keybindings.json`.

If you want to open it up, you can open up the control palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts File`. This does the same thing as clicking on that link in the non-insiders version, including creating the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: For Mac: `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `P` then click `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`

Comment: Thank you @GreeKatrina  , I had a __negative__ keybinding in there that disabled Command+Shift+Left... not cool! Got it resolved 